# VBA copy Paste from multiple workbooks into 1 on same folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel files in a same folder which contains data in worksheet "Case Tracker". I wanted to copy and paste data to all Excel files from one Excel file "`Macro.xlsx`". The code is like it copies data from `Rahul.xlsx` to `Macro.xlsx` and then from `Rohit.xlsx` to `Macro.xlsx` and so on. The problem is that while pasting data from `Rohit.xlsx` it is overlapping. The code is not finding the next available blank row to paste data and this is due to code `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select`. Can someone help me edit the code

```
Sub OpenCopyPaste()

' open the source workbook and select the source sheet
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\Test\Rahul.xlsx"

Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

' copy the source range
Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:G").Select

Selection.Copy

' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1
Windows("Macro.xlsx").Activate

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode =False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\Test\Rohit.xlsx"
Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

' copy the source range
Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:G").Select
Selection.Copy

' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1
Windows("Macro.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode =False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
```

With

```
Dim oCell As Range 'Only insert this line once!

With Sheets("Case Tracker")
    Set oCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
End With

If oCell.Row > 1 Then
    Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)
End If

oCell.Select
```

You should only declare oCell once, so only put this line once at the top:

```
Dim oCell As Range
```

Complete:

```
Sub OpenCopyPaste()
Dim oCell As Range
Dim rowCount As Integer
' open the source workbook and select the source sheet

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\Test\Rahul.xlsx"

Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

' copy the source range

With Sheets("Case Tracker")
rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowCount, 7)).Select
End With

Selection.Copy

' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

Windows("Macro.xlsx").Activate

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'------------------------------------------------
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
End With

oCell.Select
'------------------------------------------------

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\Test\Rohit.xlsx"

Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

' copy the source range

With Sheets("Case Tracker")
rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowCount, 7)).Select
End With

Selection.Copy

' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

Windows("Macro.xlsx").Activate

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'------------------------------------------------
With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set oCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With

oCell.Select
'------------------------------------------------

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. However while running thi code am getting error as "Sub or Function not defines". Any idea?

Comment: When you tried to execute the sub, did you type "OpenCopyPaste" correctly? Did you call it from the Workbook that contains the macro?

Comment: :Yes I Have called it from the Macro.xlsx and this is the workbook containing macro

Comment: Ah.. your "EndSub" should be "End Sub"

Comment: I believe this should now work... However,there is yet another problem. It is pasting data from workbook Rahul but when pasting data from workbook Rohit the code is giving error as " Runtime 1004" Copy area and paste area are not of same size. I have checked it twice but not finding any discrepancy.

Comment: When you Select Range("A:G"), you are selecting all the rows in those columns. Because a sheet has a maximum row limit, you cant select all the rows in a worksheet and then paste them below all the rows from another sheet. how may rows do you need?

Comment: I've updated the answer. This will now only copy the rows that are used.

Comment: Thank you so much Sheldon. The number of the rows I want is not defined as there can be any number of rows for a date. The columns will however constant. A:G. I have executed the code but its only copying the last row of both the workbooks.